# Convert Byte [] to PDF

Tags: c#, pdf, arrays

With help of this question [C# 4.0: Convert pdf to byte[] and vice versa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2451864/c-4-0-convert-pdf-to-byte-and-vice-versa) i was able to convert byte[] to PDF. Byte array length is 25990 approx. When i try to open the PDF it says file is corrupted. What could be the reason?

I tried the BinaryWriter but it creates PDF of 0 KB.

It's a response from a Web Service

Sample Code

```
WebResponse resp = request.GetResponse();
var buffer = new byte[4096];
Stream responseStream = resp.GetResponseStream();
{
  int count;
  do
  {
    count = responseStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
    memoryStream.Write(buffer, 0, responseStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length));
  } while (count != 0);
}
resp.Close();
byte[] memoryBuffer = memoryStream.ToArray();
System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(@"E:\sample1.pdf", memoryBuffer);
int s = memoryBuffer.Length;

BinaryWriter binaryWriter = new BinaryWriter(File.Open(@"E:\sample2.pdf", FileMode.Create));
binaryWriter.Write(memoryBuffer);
```

Comment: Where does this `byte[]` come from? What exactly does it represent? What path has it followed before it arrives as a variable in your code? Didn't you massage it forth and back to characters in the meanwhile?

Comment: Can you post your code? The question does not have enough information for an answer. By the way = 25990 bytes **are** about 25KB.

Comment: We're not clairvoyants, post the code please otherwise we will end up shooting ourselves in the foot and risk downvotes for incorrect answers that does not satisfy you!

Comment: that line is useless - int s = memoryBuffer.Length; Where's memorystream? You're not using the *using* clause...

Comment: Sorry folks. i have updated the question @Oded Since it says file is corrupted i thought still some byte might not written properly.

Comment: possible duplicate of [C# 4.0: Convert pdf to byte\[\] and vice versa](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2451864/c-sharp-4-0-convert-pdf-to-byte-and-vice-versa)

Comment: It looks like your do/while loop is bugged in that your Write() call always starts at index 0, rather than at `count`, so you're continuously overwriting the first part of the buffer.  This could work properly if the first read happens to get the entire file, though.

Comment: @PsychoDad Considering the cause of the problem might be the bug I've pointed out, I don't think this is an exact duplicate.  Maybe let OP figure out the problem with our aid first, then we can close it if it turns out to be a dupe.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are reading twice from the stream but only writing one buffer. Change this:

```
count = responseStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
memoryStream.Write(buffer, 0, responseStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length));
```

To this:

```
count = responseStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
memoryStream.Write(buffer, 0, count);
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems your missing some bytes there because you have one unnecessary read. Try this:

```
  do
  {
    count = responseStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
    memoryStream.Write(buffer, 0, count);
  } while (count != 0);
```