# How to convert byte to PDF in xamarin forms

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms

I received data from web services as byte I catch them in this property

```
   public byte[] Content { get; set; }
```

I have a web view to display the content of that byte. How to do this

is it need to convert to pdf or can these content directly called by the webview

Comment: This might help https://stackoverflow.com/a/2451878/3583859

Comment: @VijayKumbhoje  I look into this also but I need other way around so it cannot achieve like this i tried

Comment: just write the bytes to disk and then pass the path to your webview

Comment: @Jason  Can you explain it by example as an answer

Answer (score 1):

```
string myFilePath = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData), "myFile.pdf");
System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(myFilePath, Content);
```

Then like @Jason suggested, you can pass the `myFilePath` to your webview